# How does a utility 'fio' perform VFS like operations on raw unformatted devices with no filesystem on them?

Tags: filesystems, dd, storage, fio

I understand that one cannot do VFS operations on a medium with no filesystem.

Given that, how does a utility like `fio` perform VFS-like read/write/seek operations on raw devices?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `fio` specifically, but it can perform _block_ _IO_ on the block device file.  See https://lwn.net/Articles/736534/ for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that one cannot do VFS operations on a medium with no filesystem.

The question becomes "just which operations are we talking about?" which you clarify below...

> Given that, how does a utility like fio perform VFS-like read/write/seek operations on raw devices?

While read/write/seek can be done on things that have a VFS, they are **not** VFS exclusive operations - it is acceptable to issue them to devices that understand the appropriate syscalls too.

[As @andy-dalton stated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598121/how-does-a-utility-fio-perform-vfs-like-operations-on-raw-unformatted-devices#comment1116514_598121) Linux [block devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Block_devices) accept syscalls like `read()`/`write()` and `fio` just issues standard read/write library calls (which will eventually be turned into syscalls) on them (like it would a file in a filesystem) and the kernel takes care of the difference. See https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/2dd96cc46fa83a73acc1c9238c3ac59203e10213/engines/sync.c#L226-L229 as an example. This is a simplification but illustrates the overall concept.